# How to run calculations on Pandas DataFrame with Multi Index Columns (with data from yfinance)

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I'm working with yfinance in python to get price quotes for a lot of stocks (say 1000 for the Russel1000 index) to then calculate some technical indicators from that.
I use the `yf.download(symbolsstring)` method for that. It returns a pd.Dataframe that has a datetime-indicex and the columns are multiindex in the following way:

Col-Idx-Lvl1: Close           High          Low    ...

Col-Idx-Lvl2: ABC  DEF...     ABC  DEF...   ABC  DEF...

(with ABC, DEF being ticker symbols of all the stocks).

[Example Dataframe for only 2 Symbols (will be a lot more later)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51GmA.jpg)

Let's say I now want to calculate a new multiindex column for all the stocks, where I add "High" + "low" for that specific symbol.
How do I do that? Adressing it by df.loc[:, 'newcolname'] hands me a "ValueError: Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column yClose".

Of course I could take apart the dataframe into a dict of dataframes (with stocks ticker symbol names as keys) and iterate over each symbol on its own, but I would guess my calculations on thousands of symbols should be faster as a vectorized operation...?

Thanks in advance, sorry if I'm expressing my question in a weird way - it's my first post on stackoverflow...
Kind regards, Johannes

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the dataframe? It will be easier to understand your multi index and the other columns.

Comment: Here is the example Dataframe. https://i.stack.imgur.com/51GmA.jpg

Comment: Thanks. I posted one approach. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution.

1. Pull data from yfinance into a dataframe

```py
source_df = yf.download("AAPL TSLA", start="2022-01-01", end="2022-01-30")

print(source_df.columns)
```

Output confirms that we have multi index columns

```
MultiIndex([('Adj Close', 'AAPL'),
            ('Adj Close', 'TSLA'),
            (    'Close', 'AAPL'),
            (    'Close', 'TSLA'),
            (     'High', 'AAPL'),
            (     'High', 'TSLA'),
            (      'Low', 'AAPL'),
            (      'Low', 'TSLA'),
            (     'Open', 'AAPL'),
            (     'Open', 'TSLA'),
            (   'Volume', 'AAPL'),
            (   'Volume', 'TSLA')],
           )
```

2. Create a dataframe with calculation and then create multi index column.

```py
# Calculation = Sum High and Low
calculation_df = source_df['High'] + source_df['Low']

# create mutli index column
calculation_label = "High + Low"
calculation_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[calculation_label],calculation_df.columns.unique()])

calculation_df.head()
print(calculation_df.columns)
```

Output:

```
    High + Low
              AAPL       TSLA
Date        
2022-01-03  360.590012  779.036652
2022-01-04  362.059998  777.016663
2022-01-05  354.809998  750.450012
2022-01-06  346.940002  702.833313
2022-01-07  345.169998  696.976654

MultiIndex([('High + Low', 'AAPL'),
            ('High + Low', 'TSLA')],
           )
```

`calculation_df` has multi index column called "High + Low" with values for all tickers.

3. Concatenate the calculations with source

```py
final_df = pd.concat([source_df,calculation_df],axis=1)

final_df[['High','Low','High + Low']].head()
```

```
                    High                    Low                 High + Low
                AAPL    TSLA           AAPL       TSLA         AAPL     TSLA
Date                        
2022-01-03  182.880005  400.356659  177.710007  378.679993  360.590012  779.036652
2022-01-04  182.940002  402.666656  179.119995  374.350006  362.059998  777.016663
2022-01-05  180.169998  390.113342  174.639999  360.336670  354.809998  750.450012
2022-01-06  175.300003  362.666656  171.639999  340.166656  346.940002  702.833313
2022-01-07  174.139999  360.309998  171.029999  336.666656  345.169998  696.976654
```

`final_df` has a multi index column called "High + Low" with values for all tickers

Comment: Your answer utilizes vectorization, I guess? Can you estimate, how much faster this approach is vs taking apart the dataframe into a dict of dataframes (with stocks ticker symbol names as keys) and iterating over each symbol on its own? 
For lets say 100 symbols...